# Ubuntu install has frozen.

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

So I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows. So i click install alongside windows, I didn't connect to internet then I clicked Install Now. All i see is the waiting symbol and I am still on the partitioning screen.

The cd has stopped moving and I am just sitting here waiting for something to happen help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will take a while to partition - up to 5+ [hours](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132256) (see the forum linked). Just wait. The CD isn't needed in this section, it has already loaded. The hard drive should be whiring though.

Comment: It has installed but a new problem came, when i go to additional drivers, my wifi card isnt showing up

Comment: You need to ask a new question.

Comment: If I was right, please click the tick below the down arrow.

Comment: And the Ethernet port is broken

Comment: Again, a new question please.